# Time Machine deleting non-Time Machine files from disk?

Tags: time-machine, macos

I recently enabled time machine by adding an external drive as a location for Time Machine to back up to.  However, before enabling Time Machine I took a few old files (totally about 500GB) which I wanted to archive and not take space on my machine any more and copied them to a separate `Archive` folder on the external drive.  Since then I have periodically been watching the drive space to see how much Time Machine is using.

Today I discovered to my dismay that disk usage was nearly 500GB less than I expected.  I went and looked and found that all but one of my archived files had disappeared (460GB worth).  From what I had previously read it was my impression that Time Machine won't mess with files outside its directory, but now I am not so sure.  I didn't delete these files, and they are not in the trash.  Where did they go?  Can Time Machine be to blame?

Update:  I am in no way space constrained on this drive, it was less than 1/2 full when the files disappeared.

Comment: This seems odd. I've never once seen time machine touch anything outside Backups.backupd folder. Are you 100% sure that there isn't another cause of the system losing the files? How do you know that Time Machine is deleting anything on that drive?

Comment: No I'm not sure at all, but it's the only potential culprit I see and I'm rather at a loss to explain where these files went if Time Machine wasn't involved.